Inconsistent order of channels on a multi-channel sound card (ALSA, Linux)
I have a USB sound device (Startech ICUSBAUDIO7D, which comes up as ID 0d8c:0102 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM106 Like Sound Device through lsusb) which I'm trying to program the output of for 8 channels (on a Linux system, using ALSA). The python code (outputs a 50Hz sine wave) I'm using is below (each channel gets a different amplitude so I can identify them with an oscilloscope).
The sound card has 4 stereo jacks, to which I have a scope connected.
The problem is that on different runs of the program, the output mappings are not consistent - each run of the program might have the order of the channels different to the previous. So running it one time might have amplitudes (0, 0.125) on the first jack, but the next run it might have those (0.75, 0.25) on the first jack (it doesn't appear to be 'paired' per jack)
import numpy as np
import alsaaudio

def sine_wave(amplitude=1, freq=50, sample_rate=48000):
    wave_len = sample_rate/freq
    samples = (amplitude * 32767 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(wave_len) * freq / sample_rate)).astype(np.int16)
    return samples

def eightchan(freq=50, sample_rate=48000):
    wave_len = sample_rate//freq
    frames = np.zeros((wave_len, 8), dtype=np.int16)
    samples = sine_wave()
    for c in range(8):
        frames[:wave_len,c] = samples[:wave_len]*(c/8)
    return frames.tobytes()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pcm = alsaaudio.PCM(device='surround71:CARD=ICUSBAUDIO7D,DEV=0', format=alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE, channels=8, rate=48000, type=alsaaudio.PCM_PLAYBACK, periodsize=960, periods=1)
    frames = eightchan()
    while True:
        pcm.write(frames)


I'm seeing similar. (I'm using it in 5.1 mode.) If I unplug and plug it in, the order changes. It does not do this on Windows.
